# nodeunit test and trace.gl

Tags: node.js, debugging, trace, nodeunit

How to trace [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) test using [trace.gl](https://trace.gl/)

I tried in 3 ways:

- `$ node ~/Dropbox/tracegl.js ./path/To/My/NodeunitTests`. And then run my unit test from that directory in another console.
- **$ node ~/Dropbox/tracegl.js `which nodeunit` /path/To/Test/nodeUnitTestFile_test.coffee**
- $ node ~/Dropbox/tracegl.js `which nodeunit` refrence/To/Teset/nodeUnitTestFile_test.coffee -nolib

All 3 ways gives output:

> [trace.GL] See your code. This product has a commercial license.
>
> [trace.GL] WebGL trace UI: `http://localhost:2000`
>
> [trace.GL] Checking for update...[trace.GL] Serving browser JS:
>   `http://localhost:2080` up to date.

But when I open url `http://localhost:2000` I dont see any tracing information there. Just initial tracegl state.
[image: no tracing information from tracegl]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my code and using tracegl. I had to use the -nolib options to get it working. Give it a try.

Comment: `-nolib` dont help, the same result for: **$ node ~/Dropbox/tracegl.js \`which nodeunit\` refrence/To/Teset/myNodeUnit_test.coffee -nolib**